# Problem with selecting empty nodes by xsl script

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following section from my xml:

```
<paragraph>
                        <caption styleCode="Bold">Cel (uzasadnienie): </caption>
                        <content>
                            <content>     </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 1</content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 2 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>           line 3 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 4</content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 5 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>           line 6  </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 7 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 8 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content> </content>
                        </content>
                    </paragraph>
```

my xslt file contains:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3"
            xmlns:extPL="http://www.csioz.gov.pl/xsd/extPL/r1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <xsl:attribute name="key">referral</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:call-template name="join">
                    <xsl:with-param name="valueList"
                                    select="//hl7:component/hl7:section[hl7:templateId[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.13.10.3.6']]/hl7:text//hl7:paragraph"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'&#10;'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </entry>
    </map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="join">

    <xsl:param name="valueList" select="''"/>

    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="' cnt(br)=  '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(hl7:br)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'   '"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$valueList">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <!--                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(hl7:content)>0">
                        <xsl:call-template name="join">
                            <xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="hl7:content | *[not(hl7:br)]"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="' '"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="parseNode">
                            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="(normalize-space(string(.)))">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$separator "/>
                    <!--                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>-->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="count(hl7:content)>0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="join">
                                <xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="hl7:content | *[not(hl7:br)]"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="' '"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:call-template name="parseNode">
                                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="parseNode">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:if test="$node">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$node/hl7:caption">
                <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(hl7:caption)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(.,hl7:caption))"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With the line "<xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="content"/>" the call to template is functionnig correctly, template has access to list of "content" elements. But if I change it to "<xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="hl7:br"/> no list is transferred to template. And if I insert in xml `<br> test</br>`  then such element get found. Apparently empty elementst are not processed. I've tried with not(br) but without success. The output should be:

> ```
> cnt(br)=  0    cnt(br)=  0   Miejsce: 7250 Pracownia rezonansu magnetycznego
> ```

cnt(br)=  0   Cel (uzasadnienie):  cnt(br)=  9    ( )bez kontrastu (*)kontrast dożylny [ ]CITO
Opis: MR odc TH i l-s z kontrastem
Uwagi do rozpoznania:
Stan po operacji guza ogona końskiego na poziomie TH12-L4 w 2011 roku - pogorszenie osłabieni kkdd - niedowład kkdd Stan po złamaniu kości udowej lewej leczone operacyjne W 2012
Cel porady (uzasadnienie): badanie kontrolne w stosunku do 2020
Badania dotychczas wykonane:
 Mr odc l-s z 2020

Is there any solution to find all 
 elements?

With regards

Rafal Z

Comment: Post minimal but complete snippets to allow us to reproduce the problem. Saying `select="section"` works if the shown input XML doesn't have a single `section` element is quite meaningless. We don't know what the context node is, neither for `count(hl7:content)` nor for `section` nor for `br`. But if you look on the descendant axis with e.g. `.//br` or `descendant::br` (depending on namespaces you might also need `.//hl7:br` or `descendant::hl7:br`) you might have more luck.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Also include the expected result and tell us which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: I'm trying to insert my xslt, but saving fails with complaint about formatting. I'm inserting a well formatted document by Intellij with 4 spaces as required, so I have first find a way to post my xslt code.

Comment: Success by omitting the "xml version.." clause on the start of document

Answer (score 0):

Those `br` elements are not children of the `paragraph`(s) you process, they are deeper nested descendants, so try e.g. `descendant::hl7:br` to select them.

Assuming the posted input

```
<paragraph>
                        <caption styleCode="Bold">Cel (uzasadnienie): </caption>
                        <content>
                            <content>     </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 1</content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 2 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>           line 3 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 4</content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 5 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>           line 6  </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 7 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 8 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content> </content>
                        </content>
                    </paragraph>
```

the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3"
            xmlns:extPL="http://www.csioz.gov.pl/xsd/extPL/r1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <xsl:attribute name="key">referral</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </entry>
    </map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">

    <xsl:value-of select="' cnt(br)=  '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(br)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs the wanted count of 9 `br` elements.

If the input is in the namespace `urn:hl7-org:v3` e.g.

```
<paragraph xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
                        <caption styleCode="Bold">Cel (uzasadnienie): </caption>
                        <content>
                            <content>     </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 1</content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 2 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>           line 3 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 4</content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 5 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>           line 6  </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 7 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content>            line 8 </content>
                            <br/>
                            <content> </content>
                        </content>
                    </paragraph>
```

the XPath expressions adapted to use the prefix declared for the namespace (e.g. `hl7`) also work and output a count of 9:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3"
            xmlns:extPL="http://www.csioz.gov.pl/xsd/extPL/r1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <xsl:attribute name="key">referral</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </entry>
    </map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hl7:content">

    <xsl:value-of select="' cnt(hl7:br)=  '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(hl7:br)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So take that as a hint that the paths work, whether the elements are empty or not, it is just that you don't have the right context node(s). Using template matching instead of using named templates makes it much easier to change context nodes and write relative path expressions.

Comment: I've tried it, but without success. contents are not children (direct) of paragraph too, but they are porcessed, except empty contents. The proble apparently is committed to emptiness of nodes.

Comment: The shown `<xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="br"/>` doesn't make any sense, as the other XPath expressions use a namespace prefix, and while there are nested `content` there are no nested `br` so you recursive processing with `content` might work, if you want to select the `br` elements you need `<xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="descendant::hl7:br"/>`. I have not tried to figure what all that convoluted rest of the code attempts to do.

Comment: required output:
 cnt(br)=  0    cnt(br)=  0   Miejsce: 7250 Pracownia rezonansu magnetycznego&#10; cnt(br)=  0   Cel (uzasadnienie):  cnt(br)=  9    ( )bez kontrastu (*)kontrast dożylny [ ]CITO&#10; Opis: MR odc TH i l-s z kontrastem&#10; Uwagi do rozpoznania:&#10; Stan po operacji guza ogona końskiego na poziomie TH12-L4 w 2011 roku - pogorszenie osłabieni kkdd - niedowład kkdd Stan po złamaniu kości udowej lewej leczone operacyjne W 2012&#10; Cel porady (uzasadnienie): badanie kontrolne w stosunku do 2020&#10; Badania dotychczas wykonane:&#10; Mr odc l-s z 2020&#10;

Comment: I.ve edited my question to show the expected output